# What software for batch processing effects chains?

Tags: vst, plug-ins, batch-processing

I want to do batch processing of vst effects chains. I know that Steinberg Wavelab 8 supports this. Been looking for other software that can do this, but no luck so far in finding it. Most support batch processing, but not a chain of vst effects. Mostly it is limited to 'on-board' effects or just one effects. So any useful leads to a good alternative to Steinberg Wavelab 8 would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sound Forge Pro has a good, versatile batch converter with a VST effects chain. I've used it a few times myself, with good results.

Answer (score 1):

[Reaper](http://www.reaper.fm/) contains versatile batch processing capability:
[image]

[Wavosaur](http://www.wavosaur.com) does batch processing with vst chain processing (it's free):

[Smack My Batch Up](http://www.justindolby.co.uk/#!software/cinl) does the same thing with up to 5 chained plugins (also free). The author of Smack My Batch Up [posted links](http://www.lustmord.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=796) to Mac versions here also.

Comment: Smack my batch up can only be used for time-depended plugins, so it's not suited for all vst's.

Comment: Okay, I was not aware of that. Check out the Reaper addition - I just tested that myself, it seems pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

Goldwave also has batch processing, it can apply effect chains, but i haven't tried if you can insert vst effects here. You can try their trial version.

Comment: Could you provide a link?